# Unable to create AWS Glue Job without providing script location using Python Boto3

Tags: boto3, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create AWS GLUE job using Python Boto3 instead of AWS Console. I'm unable to find option to generate glue script for data transfer. AWS GLUE UI provides option to generate script when job type is Spark. [image]

how to achieve same using python boto3 or by using terraform template?

Comment: You can switch the type to 'Python Shell' to author your own Python script. However, there is no script/template auto generated by Glue in this case. You need to write it manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use create_script() function to get this working.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_script

Here is more on the Autogenerating Script AWS GLUE API documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-etl-script-generation.html#aws-glue-api-etl-script-generation-CodeGenNode